# F# and Windows Azure

Tags: azure, f#

I created a new WebAPI project that references a component that I wrote in F#.  I works fine on my local workstation.  When I deploy it to Windows Azure, I am getting this:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.IO.FileNotFoundException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.<InvokeActionWithExceptionFilters>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()</StackTrace></Error>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I set the F# .dlls to copy local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the F# .dlls to the main WebAPI project too. Otherwise it does not get included in the package uploaded to Azure.

Comment: I added it via add...reference and it still failed.  I then had to go back and mark it as copy local and it worked.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 4):

Although F# is a wonderful language, the framework support is frankly a mess. FSharp.Core doesn't ship with the normal .NET framework, but as a separate installer (e.g. [this one, for F# 3.1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41654)). By the looks of it, the Windows Azure OS images don't have F# installed at all, or at least not the version your code is compiled against.

[Here's more information about the F# versioning scheme.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362049/126014)

When the necessary version of FSharp.Core isn't available on the target computer (as is currently the case on Windows Azure), you must include FSharp.Core.dll in the package you upload. [Here's more information about running an F# ASP.NET Web API service on Azure.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/08/26/running-a-pure-f-web-api-on-azure-web-sites) Among other things, you must be sure to set the **Build Action** correctly in Visual Studio.