# Does f# 4.0 support .net 3.5?

Tags: f#, f#-4.0

Can I use 4.0 compiler to create .net 3.5 dll?

Or the minimal .net version is 4.5?

Also, could the latest version of FSharp.Core be used with .net 3.5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332046/correct-version-of-fsharp-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you select *.NET Framework 4* as the Target Framework in Visual Studio, the only F# version you can pick is *F# 3.0*:

[image: Visual Studio project properties]

If, on the other hand, you select *.NET Framework 4.5*, the option to pick *F# 4.0* becomes available as well.

Based on that, it looks as though .NET 4.5 is the minimum version for F# 4. That's only Visual Studio's view, though, so it *may* be possible that you can use F# 4 with older versions of .NET using other development tools.

If you look at [the NuGet page for FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/4.0.0.1) (currently the most recent version), you'll see that it supports these frameworks:

- .NET 2.0
- .NET 4.0
- .NET Portable Profile 7 (portable-net45+netcore45)
- .NET Portable Profile 47 (portable-net45+sl5+netcore45)
- .NET Portable Profile 78 (portable-net45+netcore45+wp8)
- .NET Portable Profile 259 (portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8)