# AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766 when building the fsharp project under AleaGPUTutorial

Tags: f#, aleagpu

I am trying to build the fsharp project within the AleaGPUTutorial project in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.  Under References, the path of the FSharp.Core.dll is shown to be C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0\FSharp.Core.dll.  So 
I assume this is not related to the question about using a different version (4.4.0.0) posted recently.  Also the error messages in the other question are different from what I am getting as quoted below.  In the other question, the error was about not able to load/find 4.3.1.0 whereas what I am getting is related to AOTCompilerServer exiting unexpectedly.

When I tried to clean build (only the fsharp project, I am not interested in the csharp one at the moment) I got the following error:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Tutorial.Fs, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  "C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\.paket\paket.exe" restore --references-files "C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\paket.references"
1>  Paket version 2.3.6.0
1>  0 seconds - ready.
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe -o:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\obj\Release\Tutorial.Fs.exe --debug:pdbonly --noframework --define:TRACE --doc:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\release\Tutorial.Fs.XML --optimize+ --platform:anycpu -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\Alea.CUDA\lib\net40\Alea.CUDA.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\Alea.CUDA.IL\lib\net40\Alea.CUDA.IL.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\Alea.CUDA.Unbound\lib\net40\Alea.CUDA.Unbound.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\Alea.IL\lib\net40\Alea.IL.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\FSharp.Charting\lib\net40\FSharp.Charting.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq\lib\net40\FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.1.0\FSharp.Core.dll" -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\FsUnit\lib\FsUnit.CustomMatchers.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\FsUnit\lib\FsUnit.NUnit.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\NUnit\lib\nunit.framework.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\OpenTK\lib\NET40\OpenTK.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\SharpDX.Direct3D9\lib\net40\SharpDX.Direct3D9.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\SharpDX\lib\net40\SharpDX.dll -r:C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\packages\SharpDX.RawInput\lib\net40\SharpDX.RawInput.dll -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Configuration.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll" -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:c887d569-3afb-4cf0-831a-00f69195ce58 --quotations-debug "C:\Users\panga\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.fs" getting_started\ParallelSquare.fs advanced_techniques\GenericTransform.fs advanced_techniques\GenericMatrixMult.fs profiling_and_performance_tuning\GenericMatrixTransp.fs examples\device_query\DeviceQuery.fs examples\basic_examples\ParallelArrayTransformation.fs examples\simple_scan\SimpleScan.fs examples\matrix_transpose\MatrixTransp.fs examples\matrix_multiplication\MatrixMult.fs examples\generic_reduce\Plan.fs examples\generic_reduce\Reduce.fs examples\generic_reduce\Sum.fs examples\generic_reduce\ScalarProd.fs examples\generic_reduce\ReduceApi.fs examples\generic_reduce\Test.fs examples\generic_scan\Plan.fs examples\generic_scan\Scan.fs examples\generic_scan\Sum.fs examples\generic_scan\ScanApi.fs examples\generic_scan\Test.fs examples\moving_average\MovingAverage.fs examples\tridiag_solver\Solver.fs examples\heat_pde\Solver.fs examples\heat_pde\Direct3d.fs examples\unbound\Reduce.fs examples\unbound\Scan.fs examples\unbound\BlockRangeScan.fs examples\unbound\MatrixMult.fs examples\unbound\Random.fs examples\cublas\Util.fs examples\cublas\Axpy.fs examples\cublas\Gemm.fs examples\cublas\GemmBatched.fs examples\cudnn\Data.fs examples\cudnn\Layer.fs examples\cudnn\Network.fs examples\cudnn\Mnist.fs examples\cudnn\Data.fs examples\cudnn\Layer.fs examples\cudnn\Network.fs examples\curand\EstimatePi.fs examples\nbody\NBody.Common.fs examples\nbody\NBody.CPU.fs examples\nbody\NBody.GPU.DynamicBlockSize.fs examples\nbody\NBody.GPU.StaticBlockSize.fs examples\nbody\NBody.OpenGL.fs examples\random_forest\DataModel.fs examples\random_forest\Cublas.fs examples\random_forest\Array.fs examples\random_forest\GpuSplitEntropy.fs examples\random_forest\RandomForest.fs examples\random_forest\Test.fs examples\random_forest\Performance.fs examples\random_forest\IrisExample.fs examples\particles\Particles.fs examples\simpled3d9\SimpleD3D9.fs Program.fs 
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\advanced_techniques\GenericMatrixMult.fs(138,37): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 2 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\advanced_techniques\GenericMatrixMult.fs(139,37): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 2 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\advanced_techniques\GenericMatrixMult.fs(140,37): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 2 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\advanced_techniques\GenericMatrixMult.fs(141,26): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 3 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\examples\matrix_multiplication\MatrixMult.fs(88,37): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 2 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\examples\matrix_multiplication\MatrixMult.fs(89,37): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 2 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\examples\matrix_multiplication\MatrixMult.fs(90,37): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 2 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\examples\matrix_multiplication\MatrixMult.fs(91,26): warning FS3189: Redundant arguments are being ignored in function 'failwith'. Expected 1 but got 3 arguments.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\examples\random_forest\GpuSplitEntropy.fs(262,25): warning FS0049: Uppercase variable identifiers should not generally be used in patterns, and may indicate a misspelt pattern name.
1>C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\src\fsharp\examples\random_forest\GpuSplitEntropy.fs(262,44): warning FS0049: Uppercase variable identifiers should not generally be used in patterns, and may indicate a misspelt pattern name.
1>    Fody: Fody (version 1.29.3.0) Executing
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   Compiling GPU code for assembly 'Tutorial.Fs.exe'...
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   Compilation environment: machineArch(X86) os(Windows) is64os(true) is64proc(false) assemblyArch(I386) assemblyRuntime(v4.0.30319)
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   Launching C:\Users\panga\project\AleaGPUTutorial\Packages\Alea.CUDA.Fody\Alea.CUDA.AOTCompileServer.net40.fs31.x86.exe process...
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766.
1> error : Fody/Alea.CUDA: AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766.
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766.
1> error : Fody/Alea.CUDA: AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766.
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   Compiling GPU code on compile server, this might take some time...
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Failed to write to an IPC Port: The parameter is incorrect.
1>
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766.
1> error : Fody/Alea.CUDA: AOTCompileServer exited unexpectly with exit code -532462766.
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] AOTCompileServer exited with exit code -532462766.
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] No results generated.
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   Compile result: 0 resources, 3 errors, 0 warnings.
1>      Fody/Alea.CUDA:   [ERROR] Compile failed, 3 errors.
1> error : Fody/Alea.CUDA: Compile failed, 3 errors.
1>    Fody:   Finished Fody 3492ms.
1>Done building project "Tutorial.Fs.fsproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Does anybody know what I might have missed?  Any pointers very much appreciated.  Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alea GPU Tutorial not compiling on VS 2015 Update 2 with FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372525/alea-gpu-tutorial-not-compiling-on-vs-2015-update-2-with-fsharp-core-4-4-0-0)

Comment: I think it's not the same bug. I encountered the same error working with VS2015. It occurred only on 1 machine out of 3 though. I am currently able to work around the error by changing the binding redirect in the file `Alea.CUDA.AOTCompileServer.net40.fs31.anycpu|x86.exe.config` in `Alea.CUDA.Fody....` from `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0"/>` to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>`. Does this work for you?

Comment: @MathiasKörner It does work!  Thank you.  Do you care to put this in as an answer and then let me mark it as the right answer?  Is this how it's supposed to work here?

Comment: @AlbertPang I guess. Good to hear that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently able to work around the error by changing the binding redirect in the file `Alea.CUDA.AOTCompileServer.net40.fs31.anycpu|x86.exe.config` in `Alea.CUDA.Fody....` from `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.3.1.0"/>` to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="4.4.0.0"/>`.