# TypeInitializationException thrown by aleagpu

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I am trying to use aleagpu but I get the System.TypeInitializationException. I have tried to google what the problem is but I couldn't find any solution, so please help.  The program is the simplest possible:

```
class Klazz
{
    private const int N = 100;
    private const int Length = 10000000;
    var gpu = Gpu.Default;// here is the Exception thrown          
    public static void Unmanaged()
    {
        var data = new int[Length];

        for (var k = 0; k < N; k++)
            gpu.For(0, data.Length, i => data[i] += 1); 
    }
}
```

I am imagining that there is something wrong in my installation, because the program is a copied example from aleagpu's homepage.

My system is:

- Windows 10
- .NET v4.5.2
- VS 2015 Community
  NVIDIA GPU computing toolkit CUDA v8.0

Alea is installed from NuGet November 9. 2016

- Alea (3.0.1)
- Alea.IL (2.2.0.3307)
- Alea.CUDA (2.2.0.3307)
- Alea.CUDA.IL
  (2.2.0.3307)
- Alea.CUDA.Unbound (2.2.0.3307)

The variables in PATH is correct.

I have tried the AleaSample.CS.ParallelForAutoMemMgt as well with the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that aleagpu is written in **F#**, and when you install **FSharp.Core** the program works. 
Thanks to Ghosthack answering the question: [Alea GPU Tutorial not compiling on VS 2015 Update 2 with FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36372525/alea-gpu-tutorial-not-compiling-on-vs-2015-update-2-with-fsharp-core-4-4-0-0)

Comment: you would think alea gpu would have all requirements,,, thank you for the solution , it works perfectly for me, side note, the latest version of FSharp.Core I found for my up to date VS2015 update 3 is 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Also, please make sure that you either install version 2.2 or version 3.x. For the new version 3.x you only need to install the Alea or the Alea.Fody package [https://www.nuget.org/packages/Alea/3.0.1][1] and do not mix with the 2.2 packages.