# I'm confused about which fsharp.core I should reference and how to do it

Tags: build, f#

I'm trying to deploy on .net 4.6 (which is what azure apps use), so I'm referencing the latest fsharp.core compatible with that framework on my `.fsproj`, which is `<TargetFSharpCoreVersion>4.4.0.0</TargetFSharpCoreVersion>`

But on my code I'm using Suave 2.0.0-rc8, which references some `fsharp.core 4.0.0.1`, the one that is available from nuget.

But somehow, it works! Can anybody give me an explanation even if it is a bit simplistic of how it works? How can there be two fsharp.cores, it seems it is not as core as it sounds.

:s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The NuGet version of FSharp.Core is not equal to the assembly version of FSharp.Core.**

[The versioning scheme for FSharp.Core is confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362049/126014), but when you use FSharp.Core in a .NET 4.6 application, the *assembly* version is 4.4.0.0, even though it's bundled in a NuGet package with the version 4.0.0.1.

You can investigate this yourself inside of Visual Studio. As an example, I have a small application that has these NuGet dependencies:

```
Id                                  Versions 
--                                  -------- 
FsCheck                             {2.6.2}  
FsCheck.Xunit                       {2.6.2}  
FSharp.Core                         {4.0.0.1}
Unquote                             {3.1.2}  
xunit.abstractions                  {2.0.0}  
xunit.extensibility.core            {2.1.0}  
xunit.extensibility.execution       {2.1.0}
```

You will notice that the NuGet version of FSharp.Core is 4.0.0.1.

If you find the reference in Solution Explorer, you can find the actual `.dll` file that contains FSharp.Core. If you open this with Reflector or the Visual Studio object browser, you'll see that the assembly version is, in fact, 4.4.0.0.

Comment: Sí, if I'm already referencing 4.4.0.0 I shouldn't need to reference 4.0.0.1 or I still need to reference just because they're strictly speaking not the same and some libraries declare one as their dependency and other libraries declare the other as their dependency?

Comment: @LayGonzález See updated answer. The _assembly_ FSharp.Core 4.4.0.0 is bundled in the _NuGet package_ FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1.

Comment: Now I see! one is an assembly, the other is a package. Thanks a lot!